# How can I import a SQL-file into my MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have exported a SQL-database and right now I have a SQL-file. I am using a MongoDB (with Studio 3T). I want to import my SQL-file into the MongoDB, but in Studio 3T I can only see a menu for a connection to a SQL-database. Is there a way to import my SQL-file directly into the MongoDB?

Comment: How did you export the SQL database? A CSV file can be imported with [mongoimport](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/) tool.

Comment: I exported it as a SQL-file

Comment: This you cannot import. Best export format would be CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because MongoDB and SQL are two different types of databases with separate data formats and query languages, you cannot directly import a SQL file into MongoDB.

You have to perform a data transformation process if you want to transfer data from a SQL database to MongoDB.

Comment: Ahh okay thanks. What is the easiest way: json or csv? Or maybe something else?

Comment: transformed data is in a JSON format

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked as smooth as butter!